# How fix MRO when you inherit int in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, method-resolution-order

I have in my code biiiig numbers, like quadrillions and quintillions. So I build a fancy converter for them

```
class Repr:
    def __str__(self):
        # magic
        return '123.456qa'
   
    def __repr__(self):
        for parent in self.__class__.__mro__:
            if parent in [self.__class__, Repr]:
                continue
            return f'{self.__class__.__name__}' \
                   f'({parent.__repr__(self)})'
        raise ValueError('how this is possible?')
```

Now I am trying to use it

```
class MyValue(Repr, int):
    pass

v = MyValue(123.4*10**12)
print(v)         # expected '123.4t'
print(f'{v!r}')  # expected 'MyValue(123400000000000)'
```

What I fail to understand - is how MRO works if I switch parents `class MyValue(int, Repr)`

According to all known documentation, this should behave as `int`. Because int is first, int has both `__repr__` and `__str__`.

That is true in the case of converting to string

```
class MyValue(int, Repr):
    pass

v = MyValue(123.4*10**12)
print(f'{v!r}')  # expected '123400000000000'
```

Debug shows, that `Repr.__repr__` is not even used.

*BUT*!
`Repr.__str__` is used!

```
print(v)         # expected `123400000000000`
'123.4t'         # actual result
```

Why do we have so much inconsistency? Why is this behavior not according to documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` only defines its own `__repr__`, not its own `__str__`. It inherits `__str__` from `object`. When you define `class MyValue(int, Repr)`, `Repr` comes before `object` in the MRO, so `Repr.__str__` gets used instead.